# How to count a range of values in datastudio

Tags: csv, google-sheets, looker-studio

I am trying to transform a report that I have made in sheets into the newest datastudio tool. In my sheet, I have a table where there are several columns that holds data related (this is because each row could have more than one value so I used the "split text into columns" function to represent).

What I have is something similar to:

| ID | Component | Component 1 | Component 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | wood | metal | gold |
| 102 | metal | copper |  |
| 103 | wood | gold | metal |

In my excel, I have a formula to count the time a certain component is shown by using `=COUNTIF(<range>,<string>)`

Therefore, with the above formula, I have something similar to:

| Component | count |
| --- | --- |
| wood | 2 |
| metal | 3 |
| copper | 1 |
| gold | 2 |

I want to be able to build the same in datastudio. Turns out that since the components are divided into columns, I can only use one dimension and the result only shows the count of the first column.

I want to know if there is an easy way to accomplish this. My original data source is like this:

| ID | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | wood;metal;gold |
| 102 | meta;copper |
| 103 | wood;gold;metal |

Maybe it's easier to work directly with the previous format but again, using the component in this case only counts for the first occurrence and not across the whole string.

For now, the only solution I can think of is splitting the text into rows instead of columns, but that is not feasible achievable using Google Sheets, or at least not that I am aware of.

Could somebody have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

## Edit

I am adding here the minimal reproducible example. [This is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_8TEG-ANFpIrjk20RKqp66_x7YA62fKp63Amb5-b2s/edit?usp=sharing) that I have (example) and the current report I am using so far (built-in sheets):
Now, I want to have the same report (plus more things) using datastudio. [This is the report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/14d5322c-c11e-4973-90aa-8b39c91e6921) example I have in data studio. As you will see the `record count` for components is not accurate in DataStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a preliminary answer.  I'll polish if we like it and delete it otherwise.

Consider the following sheet:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Range A2:B4 contains my data of interest.  Rows 7:10 show the results I think you are looking for.  The mechanism for creating this is the value of cell A6 which contains:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(B2:B4,";")), "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1)  WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1"))
```

At the highest level, the formula splits each of the delimited text items into their own cell and then flattens all these cells into one column against which we then run a SQL query against the sheet to group and count them.

Comment: Hello @Kolban, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not adapt well to my use case. I am trying to create a datastudio project with several data that I already have on sheets. In sheets, for having the same info you are displaying, I first split text into columns and then used the formula =COUNTIF('<range>,<component value>). That is working, but I want to adapt this to datastudio and I want to have a table in datastudio that shows the same info. The number of components. I will prepare an example.

Comment: Hello @Kolban I added an example in my question to be able to explain myself better in what I want to achieve and what the current problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm drawing a blank.  From what I see, given EXACTLY the Google Sheet, I don't see how we can sum up the data as is.  You have columns components, components 1 and components 2 ... I am imagining these could go on to components 3 and more.  In the Sheets code in this possible answer, we can create a new sheet from the original sheet which would give the numbers you want.  How locked into the sheet you are using for data are you?  What about stepping back and looking at the problem holistically.  Precisely what data do you get initially and where does it "land".

Comment: Hello @Kolban. I have full control over the spreadsheet. I can change to better adapt to the data. In fact, the components column is originally only one field with the different components together separated by ";". I use the "split text into columns" later.

Comment: Hello Kolban, I used your formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(B2:B4,";")), "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1)  WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1"))` which works but I need also the date for use this as a data range dimension. If in the raw data there is a column date, how can I also carry that with the formula?

Comment: I think the only solution I can think of, is to duplicate the entire row and add the second component in the duplicated one. Something like:
`| 101 | wood | \n
| 101 | metal | \n
| 101 | gold |`
And then group by ID...

Comment: @neteot - Can you elaborate on the date column?  Can you share some example data and what you would like the final result to look like?